# Changing the name of a file and moving it to a folder with the same name

Tags: bash, file, directory

I am trying to keep some media files organized - from naming convention to folder hierarchy. The files are kept on a server so having this run as a cron is the best bet. The main issue is that some of the images, depending on who takes them, are not named appropriately.

The folder structure that I currently have is:

```
    Landscapes (2012)
    Buildings (2013)
    Contemporary Designs (2014)
    etc.
```

Files are saved as:

```
    Landscapes 010 (2012).jpg # correct
    Landscapes 011 (2012).jpg # correct
    Landscapes (2012) 012 (Regional_Airport).jpg #sometimes happens and need to delete the (Regional_Airport)
```

- I would like the file names to be trimmed to keep the name date and the sequence #(regardless of the position) *fancy would be to keep them all in the same order, where for example (Regional_Airport) would be removed and 012 placed in front of (2012).
- Move the file into the folder that has the same name and year

I am fairly limited in my scripting abilities, but found this while messing with Hazel (which is a limited option, because my computer does not stay on all day).

```sh
#!/bin/bash
RootFolder=/Volumes/image_store

# split only on new line
OLDIFS="$IFS"  # save it
IFS="
"
file="$1"
for folder in $(ls -1 $RootFolder/)  ; do

ufolder=`echo $folder | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
ufile=`echo $file | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`

if grep -q $ufolder <<< $ufile ; then
mv $file to $RootFolder/$folder
/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -m "Moved $file to $folder in Image_Store" ImageMover
exit 0
fi

done

IFS=OLDIFS
```

Comment: Well - you could use a regex like `\w+ \d{3,} \(\d{4}\).jpg` to check that your names are in the specified format. But as for fixing them, you'd have a lot of assumptions to make.. for instance, if the index number was 2009, but the year was 2010, and the human entered them in the reverse places - how would you know?

Comment: There is no catch-all solution to be had here. Any script you come up with is going to have to make some assumptions about how files are named, since there's nothing stopping a user from naming a file `foobarbaz.xyz.jpg` or any number of other useless and incorrect names. In cases like these, there is no recovery possible without human intervention. I'm assuming this isn't exactly news to you, though. So your best bet may be to use a set of regexes to catch the most common naming errors, although as problemPotato points out, even if a file matches the regex, you might still get bad results.

Comment: You are both right. How could I work in a regex to deal with the two most common (problemPotato - you are on to something), \w+ \d{3,} \(\d{4}\).jpg and \w+ \(\d{4}\) +d{3,}.jpg. Thanks